# Forum for discussing research paper

Tags: online-resource, reading, literature, independent-researcher, reproducible-research

I am trying to implement an algorithm given in a paper. I have some questions which I would like to clear out since implementation requires complete clarity on all the concepts/algorithms/arguments introduced the paper. I have contacted the authors of the paper multiple times(5-6 times) through mail but I do not receive any response and it's been close to a month now.

I would like to know if there is any forum/website in which a reader of a research paper can submit questions that he/she faces while reading it, which is also subscribed by the authors of the paper and authors of papers citing that in their reference section.

P.S.: This question may seem to be duplicate of: 
[Whom to discuss research papers with?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7875/whom-to-discuss-research-papers-with)

But in my case, I am not from academia and do not have any advisor/mentor sort of person to discuss paper with.

Comment: 5 -6 mails within a month to a (probably more senior) colleague or professor, who you do not know personally is rude. If you want to get a reply next time, please do not do that again.

Comment: @Alexandros Thanks, I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, such a forum does not exist (even though it actually sounds like a reasonable idea in theory). The closest I can think of is the Questions & Answers section at [ResearchGate](http://www.researchgate.net), though to be honest I have stopped checking in there because most questions in my fields are simply not very interesting. Depending on your topic, you may also be well served posting in a topically appropriate Stack Exchange site.

Comment: I explored ReasearchGate Question & Answer section and it seems appropriate for my purpose(found discussions about my topic of interest).

Comment: You might also try the Scientific Computing StackExchange.

Comment: Agreed, [scicomp.SE], or whichever Stack Exchange site is appropriate for the topic of the paper, should be a good place to get guidance on this.

Comment: [PubPeer](https://pubpeer.com/) serves similar purpose.

Comment: I believe PubPeer is the most correct/ relevant answer to this question, but can't post due to the question being protected.

Comment: this is probably the best ressource on the internet  , they are phd grad student forums such as phinished , maybe few discussion on research gate , and some groups on social networks , but nothing organised like stack exchange.